# Is it possible to have users log in and out of handsets?

Tags: voip, asterisk

I have a scenario where users need to be able to move between desks.

Is it possible to configure Asterisk so that users can log in and out of any handset, and their calls route to whichever handset they are logged into?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, although the concept of a "user" does not really exist as a unified concept in Asterisk (despite the existence of users.conf).  Check out the relational database section in Asterisk: The Definitive Guide, in which the authors describe implementing hot-desking in the dialplan:

[Asterisk TDG: Relational Database Integration](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596517342/asterisk-DB.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your Q or not.
But I am giving you an answer based on my understanding.

Asterisk support so many voip protocol.
As far as concern to SIP then asterisk not bind user with any handset or IP until you specify in sip.conf.

So if user is free to REGISTER from any where you can do log out from one client(PC) & log in from other client. Your call route to current registered client.

But if your registration get overlapped then call route to last registered client.
Asterisk not support call forking feature.